# Constructing a O(n) time complexity algorithm for search for a value in two arrays

Tags: arrays, big-o

Say I have 2 int arrays that are sorted in ascending order. and I am trying to find if there is a value from Array A that matches a value in Array B while having a time complexity of Big-O of n. At first I thought of linear search but it wasnt possible because I needed a nested for loop. My other idea was trying to use a binary search and add an for loop to that. Would that work?

So like...

```
for (int i = 0;i<B.length(), i++) {
   BinarySearch(A[0..N-1], value, low, high) {
       if (high < low)
           return -1 // not found
       mid = low + (high - low) / 2
       if (A[mid] > value)
           return BinarySearch(A, value, low, mid-1)
       else if (A[mid] < value)
           return BinarySearch(A, value, mid+1, high)
       else
           return mid // found
   }
}
```

this isnt a complete code, I just copied this from wiki as an example. Am i going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge both lists, merge is O(n).

Merge procedure would be:

1) Compare "smallest element" of both lists, if they are equal, it forms our answer.
2) If not remove the smaller of the two from the list and update the list.
3) Repeat 1) and 2) till any of the list is finished.

complexity would be Min(a.length, b.length) which may be O(1) also if one array is comparatively very small than other.

Comment: why is MergeSort O(n)? because the way i learned it is that the worst case for Merge is Theta(nlgn)

Comment: I talked about merge operation of the merge sort, which is O(n). Merge sort is 1) Recursively sort left half T(n/2) 2) Recursively sort right half T(n/2) 3) Merge both sorted halves O(n). Since both list are already sorted, we just need to perform merge which is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You say the arrays are *sorted* already. That's the very important precondition you have to work with. Then, you have two sequences like this:

```
 1 <A   -7
 2       0
 5 <B    1 <A
10       5 <B
13      11
14      13
```

Imagine you walk the sequences in parallel from top to bottom, trying to balance indexes in such a way that values at those indexes match — see the marks `<A` and `<B` in my example. The rest is just using integer comparisons. That will result in an `O(Max(a.Length, b.Length))` (hence `O(n)`) time complexity.

Possible improvement: At the beginning figure out whether it makes sense to walk the inputs at all.

The rest if really left as a homework.

Answer (score -1):

sample code to show how python is self explanatory ;)

```
def find_first_matching_value(array_a, array_b):
    "Return the first value in both arrays"
    # both arrays are sorted
    assert sorted(array_a) == array_a
    assert sorted(array_b) == array_b
    array_a_index = 0
    array_b_index = 0
    while (array_a_index < len(array_a)
           and array_b_index < len(array_b)):
        if array_a[array_a_index] > array_b[array_b_index]:
            # skip to next element in array b
            array_b_index += 1
        elif array_a[array_a_index] < array_b[array_b_index]:
            # skip to next element in array a
            array_a_index += 1
        else:
            # found
            return array_a[array_a_index]
```

Comment: -1, I think that a self-explanatory Python code won't help the OP to *learn something* and figure out his homework *himself*.

Comment: the point was to show him no need of library BinarySearch function, but anyway...

Comment: I think i kind of understand it. I guess i need to understand how to measure complexity instead. Is this in O(n) because the while runs the length of A, and the operations inside the loop is O(1)?

Comment: yes, to measure complexity, you should take the worst possible case (for homeworks, in real life average complexity may be more useful)

Comment: Also can I say if an algorithm has theta(n) complexity, I can be certain that the same algorithm has Big-O(n) complexity?